# Facebook CodelessIAPAutoLog error is crashing The project

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine

I recently installed the latest version of facebook sdk 7.11.1 for unity to use in my game project, I imported the sdk without any problems But whenever I try to run the project, this error pops up!

here is the error log

```
ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:371)
    Facebook.Unity.CodelessIAPAutoLog.FindTypeInAssemblies (System.String typeName, System.String nameSpace)
    Facebook.Unity.CodelessIAPAutoLog.FindObjectsOfTypeByName (System.String typeName, System.String nameSpace)
    Facebook.Unity.CodelessIAPAutoLog.addListenerToIAPButtons (System.Object listenerObject)
    Facebook.Unity.Editor.EditorFacebookGameObject.OnAwake ()
    Facebook.Unity.FacebookGameObject.Awake ()
    UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
    Facebook.Unity.ComponentFactory:GetComponent(IfNotExist)
    Facebook.Unity.Editor.EditorFacebookLoader:get_FBGameObject()
    Facebook.Unity.CompiledFacebookLoader:Start()
```

And this is the code I used that caused this error :

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (!FB.IsInitialized)
    {
        FB.Init();
    }
    else
    {
        FB.ActivateApp();
    }
}

public void LogIn()
{
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(callback: OnLogIn);
}

void OnLogIn(ILoginResult result)
{
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;
    }
}

public void Share()
{
    FB.ShareLink(new Uri("google play link"), callback: Onshare);
}

private void Onshare(IShareResult result)
{
    if (result.Cancelled || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
    {
        Debug.Log("ShareLink Error " + result.Error);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.PostId))
    {
        Debug.Log(result.PostId);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Share Successful");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Seems this error only appeared in Unity 2018 which is still in beta, works fine on version 2017.1/2017.2/2017.3